# Error when analysing code (pylint) on Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, python-3.7, pylint, pathlib

I use Spyder 5 (Python 3.7.9), although I also installed Python 3.9 but not with Spyder.
When I press F8 to run a Static Analysis Code, a message displays:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\obj\windows-release 37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\runpy.py", line 193, in
_run_module_as_main
File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\runpy.py", line 85, in
_run_code
File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\pylintmain.py", line 9, in <<module> pylint.run_pylint()
File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\pylint_init.py", line 21, in run_pylint from pylint.lint import Run as PylintRun
File "C:\Program Files\Spyder pkgs\pylint\lint_init.py", line 75, in <module> from pylint.lint.parallel import check_parallel
File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\pylint\lint\parallel.py", line 7, in <module>
from pylint import reporters File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\pylint\reportersinit.py", line 25, in <module>
from pylint import utils
File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\pylint\utils_init__.py", line 45, in <module>
from pylint.utils.ast walker import ASTWalker
File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\pylint\utils\ast_walker.py", line 6, in <module>
from astroid import nodes
File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\astroidinit.py", line 46, in <module>
from pathlib import Path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pathlib'
```

Before installing Spyder 5 (I had Spyder 3), it worked, but since I've updated Spyder, it won't anymore.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a bug in our Windows installer and we'll try to fix it in our next version, to be released in June.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you're in fact using python2 and not python 3.7. Your default python might be python2 so you should try using `python3` instead of `python` when launching commands, or try changing the default python for your system (if at all possible).